# Issue to create a horizontal navigation menu (nokia-like)

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I'm trying to make a Nokia-like horizontal menu (like [here](http://www.nokia.com/fr-fr/accessoires/accessoire/md-50w/)) but without success.
As you can see on my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAA7g/) I can't get the white background of the active menu item to take the full height of the blue menu-container minus 1 px at the top. How could I achieve that? Many thanks

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="menu-container">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Category 1</li>
            <li class="active">Category 2</li>
            <li> <a title="" href="">Category 3</a> 
            </li>
            <li>Category 4</li>
            <li>Category 5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End DIV Menu -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: #124191;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
#menu {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
#menu ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #124191;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #fff;
}
#menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    /* This is the sub-menu items */
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li a:active {
    background: fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:
Add this to `#menu ul`:

```
#menu ul {
   height:49px; 
   margin:0;
}
```

and this to `#menu ul li`:

```
#menu ul li {
   height:100%;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAA7g/3/)

Comment: Thanks. Almost, but the issue with this solution is that the menu items (Category 1, Category 2, etc) are no longer vertically aligned to the middle of the blue menu-container unfortunately

Comment: @Greg Glad I could help. If you're wondering what made the menu items vertically aligned to the middle it was this code: `line-height:49px; height:49px;` They having the same numeric value did the trick! :)

Comment: Thanks. One more thing if you don't mind, would you know why the a:active doesn't work? (I put class="active" for item "Category 3", see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DeK98/ Thanks

Comment: @Greg If I understand you correctly you want that specific menu item to have that stylfe by default on specific pages? In that case, what about changing to having the class on the `a` tag? Like this: `<li > <a title="" class="active" href="">Category 3</a>`

Comment: @Greg and change the css selector to this: `#menu ul li a.active`.